# Does an answer to a closed question count for the Windows 8 Challenge?

Tags: support, windows-8-challenge

The relevant post is https://superuser.com/a/494936/168055.

It is clear that posts that are closed do not count. What about answers to closed questions?

Comment: You could always check between the answers you've posted on the windows 8 tag (click on your username - this will add your usernumber to the search, then add [windows-8]), then compare it against the contest page

Answer (score 3):

No it doesn't. Under the Eligibility Section:

> Posts that are deemed off-topic and are deleted or closed will not count.